# how to show cover image inside input box making input field transparent?

Tags: html, css

i have a page having a background cover image , my input boxes have only border-bottom , the problem is input field is now showing white as a background which is not looking good , i want to make them transparent taking that cover background , how to do it please help ?

here is my code login.html file:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="body">

            <form name="form" ng-submit="login()" role="form">
            <div class="list-inset">
                <div class="login-div-outer">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="USERNAME" ng-model="data.username" class=" m-item" required>
                </div>

               <div class="login-div-outer">
                        <input type="password"  name="password" id="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" ng-model="data.password" class=" m-item" required >
                </div>

            </div>
            </form>

                <button class="button button-full m-login-btn" type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" ng-click="login()" eat-click-if="!checkNetwork(true)">
        login
                </button>

  </body>

</html>



css that i have tried  : 

    .body{
       background-image: url('https://images.blogthings.com/thecolorfulpatterntest/pattern-1.png');
      background-size: cover;

    }

    .m-item{
      width: 93%;
        border: none !important;
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey !important;
        /* background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); */
        outline: none!important;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        /* background: transparent; */
        font-size: 16px !important;
    }
```

i have added a plunker link for example :

```
        https://plnkr.co/edit/auDZZJrqx6b6iv4MvU1p?p=preview

what i want to do is input should also show the background image so that when the background image is light in color white color should not get shown as it does'nt looks good
```

Answer (score 0):

just add below css in .m-item { } class

```
.m-item { background: transparent none repeat scroll 0 0; }
```